# RangeSlider and RangeSliderState don't work together as expected

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, compose-recomposition

I am trying to use the [RangeSlider](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary#RangeSlider(androidx.compose.material3.RangeSliderState,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.material3.SliderColors,androidx.compose.foundation.interaction.MutableInteractionSource,androidx.compose.foundation.interaction.MutableInteractionSource,kotlin.Function1,kotlin.Function1,kotlin.Function1)) with [RangeSliderState](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/RangeSliderState) in the Jetpack Compose(**1.2.0-alpha05**).
First, I drag the first thumb and everything works fine. But when I drag the other thumb, the previous thumb jumps to its initial value!
The old implementation (*without RangeSliderState*) works fine. **I want to use the new version** for its ability to customize the thumbs and tracker.

[image]

This is my Composable :

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun MyRangeSlider(
    min: Float,
    max: Float,
    value1: Float,
    value2: Float,
    onValueChange: (Float,Float) -> Unit,
) {
    RangeSlider(
        state = RangeSliderState(
            initialActiveRangeStart = value1,
            initialActiveRangeEnd = value2,
            initialOnValueChange = {
                onValueChange(it.start, it.endInclusive)
            },
            valueRange = min..max,
            onValueChangeFinished = {}
        )
    )
}
```

And this is the way that I call it :

```
var a by remember { mutableStateOf(25f) }
var b by remember { mutableStateOf(75f) }

MyRangeSlider(
    min = 0f,
    max = 100f,
    value1 = a,
    value2 = b,
    onValueChange = { v1: Float, v2: Float ->
        a=v1
        b=v2
    })
```

Is there a problem with my code or is there something else?

Answer (score 1):

`RangeSlider` in `material3` is very easy you can follow this example.

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun RangeSliderDemo() {
    val rangeSliderState = remember {
        RangeSliderState(
            0f,
            100f,
            valueRange = 0f..100f,
            onValueChangeFinished = {
               
            }
        )
    }
    val startInteractionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
    val endInteractionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
    val startThumbAndTrackColors = SliderDefaults.colors(
        thumbColor = Color.Blue,
        activeTrackColor = Color.Red
    )
    val endThumbColors = SliderDefaults.colors(thumbColor = Color.Green)
    Column {
        Text(text = (rangeSliderState.activeRangeStart..rangeSliderState.activeRangeEnd).toString())
        RangeSlider(
            state = rangeSliderState,
            modifier = Modifier.semantics { contentDescription = "Localized Description" },
            startInteractionSource = startInteractionSource,
            endInteractionSource = endInteractionSource,
            startThumb = {
                SliderDefaults.Thumb(
                    interactionSource = startInteractionSource,
                    colors = startThumbAndTrackColors
                )
            },
            endThumb = {
                SliderDefaults.Thumb(
                    interactionSource = endInteractionSource,
                    colors = endThumbColors
                )
            },
            track = { rangeSliderState ->
                SliderDefaults.Track(
                    colors = startThumbAndTrackColors,
                    rangeSliderState = rangeSliderState
                )
            }
        )
    }
}
```

**Preview**
[image: preview]

Comment: Thank you for your reply Chirag, This is the old API implementation, It works fine. I want to use the new version for its ability to customize the thumb and tracker. New API implementation requires RangeSliderState

Comment: Check out the new example with updated code with RangeSliderState

Comment: My friend my problem is not with the customization part, you use remember with RangeSliderState, In my case, as you can see in the second paragraph of my question, I keep the initial values in two different states (a,b state hoisting). in fact I use a and b as reference states, not the RangeSliderState itself

Comment: But why you want to keep it separate

Comment: Because of app logic! I found the problem, It is because of overriding initialOnValueChange!!!